# jQuery Mobile Responsive Tables not working

Tags: jquery-mobile

I've been working with jQuery Mobiles new responsive tables. I've got 3 tables, 2 of them work perfectly as expected but for some reason the final one refuses to work.

Here's the code:

```
<table data-role='table' id='TableProfile' class='ui-responsive table-stroke'>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th data-priority='persist'>#</th>
        <th data-priority='persist'>Title</th>
        <th>Author</th>
        <th>Publisher</th>
        <th>Edition</th>
        <th data-priority='3'>Condition</th>
        <th data-priority='2'>Price</th>
        <th>Sold</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Thomas Calculus Early Transcendentals</td>
        <td>MD.Weir, GB.Thomas Jr, J. Hass, FR.Giordano</td>
        <td>Brooks/Cole</td>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>750</td>
        <td><input type='button'  value='Sold' name=70/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Thomas Calculus Early Transcendentals</td>
        <td>MD.Weir, GB.Thomas Jr, J. Hass, FR.Giordano</td>
        <td>Brooks/Cole</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>1000</td>
        <td><input type='button'  value='Sold' name=73/></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>

</table>
```

I am using the jQuery Mobile version 1.3 but I'n sure why this table isn't working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there is a bug some where since this feature is new. Now what fixed my problem was to completely close the tab I was working in and then opening up the website again and it worked.  Refreshing the page won't fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you're using jQuery > 1.7? jQuerymobile needs jQuery 1.7 or higher to function.

I've tried it and it seems to work.

The standard way of doing it is:

```
   <table data-role="table" id="my-table" data-mode="reflow">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Rank</th>
          <th>Movie Title</th>
          <th>Year</th>
          <th><abbr title="Rotten Tomato Rating">Rating</abbr></th>
          <th>Reviews</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>1</th>
          <td><a href="foo.com" data-rel="external">Citizen Kane</a></td>
          <td>1941</td>
          <td>100%</td>
          <td>74</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Working example of your code: http://jsfiddle.net/AYSJZ